# DataService in Test env always return null when fetching InMemoryDb data

Tags: c#, .net, testing, .net-core

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    private readonly Mock<ICarService> _carServiceMock;
    public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
        _carServiceMock = new Mock<ICarService>();
    }

    public override void ConfigureMyServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(_carServiceMock.Object);
    }

    public override void ConfigureDatabase(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CarContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("CarDb"));
        services.AddTransient<DataSeed>();
    }   
}

public class TestFixture: IDisposable, ICollectionFixture<TestFixture>
{
    public TestFixture()
    {
         _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
            .UseEnvironment("Development"));
          _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

Inside Controller I'm using `ICarService` which is using `CarContext` to retrieve data from the Db.

```
public class CarController
{
    private readonly ICarService _carService;

    public CarController(ICarService carService)
    {
        _carService = carService;            
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        var contact = await _carService.GetAsync(id); **// this is always null**
    }
}
```

My question is:
Since this is an integration test, do I need to mock ICarService in the first place and if so, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing how the `CarService` class interacts with the database then you shouldn't be mocking it.

What you want to do is use the real `CarService` implementation and let dependency injection add the InMemoryDatabase into that class as the `CarContext` parameter.

So, remove the `Mock<ICarService>` and register the real one instead.

**Why is it returning null?**

In you example, when you call the method `_carService.GetAsync(id)` it is calling the mock class. But you haven't `Setup` any methods on the mock so any calls will return `null`.

You need to add the following to cause the mocked method to return a value:

```
_carService.Setup(cs => cs.GetAsync(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(1);
```

But this would not call the in memory database as you are using a mock for `CarService`.